# How to avoid PhotoSwipe zoomed to image original size in SmartSevice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, photoswipe

I use PhotoSwipe with angularJS to display image.But when I click the image in SmartDevice, the default mode is set to 'zoomIn' which is too big to see the image.

I mean, when I click an image like this 
[image]

It became this:

[image]

but I want it to become this for default:

[image]

this is the html :

```
            <a ng-click="showZoom(page.page);">
                <img ng-src="{{page.imageUrl}}" >
            </a>
```

this is the javascript:

```
$scope.showZoom = function (pageNo) {
    var items = new Array();
                items.push(
                        {
                            src: $scope.pages[0].imageUrl,
                            w: 1400,
                            h: 700
                        });
                var currentIndex = 0;
                if (pageNo === 1)
                    currentIndex = 1;
                if (pageNo >= 2)
                    currentIndex = pageNo / 2 + 1;

                //オプションの設定
                var options = {
                    history: false,
                    focus: false,
                    index: currentIndex,
                    showAnimationDuration: 0,
                    hideAnimationDuration: 0,

                };
                var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];
                var gallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
                gallery.init();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problerm.
It's because i use 'ngTouch' which cause the 'ng-click' fired twice that is like a double-click.

in PhotoSwipe, a double-click means zoomIn, so.....

I remove the 'ngTouch' and  get resolved.